# Integrating Quickfix/n with SQL Server Integration services

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, quickfix

I am trying to integrate Quickfix/n with SSIS using Script task. I have referenced the Quickfix.dll to the script task, created derived class which inherits features from Message cracker like:

```
class FixApp : QuickFix.MessageCracker
```

But when ever I try to call this class from Script main class of SSIS, I get

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

what am I missing here? isn't only referencing the dll enough for ssis to use its class and methods?

EDIT: following is the TradeClient class that I have included in the SSIS script task and Main method that calls all other.

TradeClient class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using QuickFix;
using QuickFix.Fields;

namespace ST_a35ec6dde06549f0a96ac08576735ad8 
{
    class TradeClientApp:MessageCracker
    {


   public void FromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
        {
            Crack(message, sessionID);
        }
    }
}

public void Main()
        {
            try
            {

               TradeClientApp tradeclient = new TradeClientApp();         
               SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(file);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some of your Script Task code?     Which version of .NET is your Script Task set to use?

Comment: @troy, I have added the script as you suggested. I am currently using VS2010 for development and .Net version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `using QuickFix;` to the top of your Script Task in order to invoke the [QuickFIX/n library](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/creating-an-application).

Comment: 'Using Quickfix;' is there at the top of the code, and i still got that error.